# AWS EC2 session manager access

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, ubuntu, amazon-ec2, pipeline

I am trying to access my AWS EC2 console via session manager which was working perfectly fine before, I was testing out some Ubuntu sources list and removed openssh-client `(apt-get remove)` accidentally and then re-installed it again `(apt-get install)`.

Now I am trying to access the EC2 command line via session manager but it says:

> The version of SSM Agent on the instance supports Session Manager, but
> the instance is not configured for use with AWS Systems Manager.
> Verify that the IAM instance profile attached to the instance includes
> the required permissions.

I have not changed any settings or configurations in AWS, just getting the following error message when I try to access EC2 via session manager.

clueless right now, what steps to take in order to get back AWS session manager access

Answer (score 0):

Go to your EC2 console, Actions, and then Security.  Check your IAM role to make sure you have given permission to SSM to connect to your instance.

Also, SSM uses temporary SSH keys behind the scenes.  I think they're generated "on demand" but you might try uninstalling and reinstalling the SSM agent if the above doesn't help you.

Comment: will it down the instance in any cases?

Comment: also is it important to uninstall SSM agent via EC2 command-line, if yes then i don't have command-line access.

Comment: i've checked, the sam IAM role is assigned to another instance and I can access command-line via session manager to that ec2 instance.

Answer (score 0):

The issue I had is that I wasn't waiting for a short while before test after assigning IAM role to the session manager.

Wait for a few minutes when testing your Session manager access after assigning IAM role.